# Upload video to Vimeo using URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, video, upload, vimeo

Im trying to upload a video to Vimeo , using their rest API.
First I make a POST, to create the video on the API, then I select the video from camera, and send a PATCH with some parameters.
The problem is, the video seems to upload with success, I get a HTML without any errors that seems a success, but in the site doesn't show the video, and the KB size is only 0.

Here's my PATCH method :

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos")
    request.httpMethod = "PATCH"
    request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    request.httpBody = mediaData // Data()
    request.setValue("Upload-Offset", forHTTPHeaderField: "0")
    request.setValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/offset+octet-stream")
    request.setValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: "Bearer 1233131312")
    request.setValue("Tus-Resumable", forHTTPHeaderField: "1.0.0")
    let newTask = session.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request)
    newTask.resume()
```

and already tried with:

```
request.httpBodyStream = InputStream(data: mediaData)
```

or:

```
session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data)
```

Heres is the documentation from VIMEO :

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos

Can anyone have an example or snippet that actually works?

[UPDATE]:

The class that make the request:

```
import Foundation

case get
case post
case put
case delete
case patch

var verbName: String {
    switch self {
    case .get:
        return "GET"
    case .post:
        return "POST"
    case .put:
        return "PUT"
    case .delete:
        return "DELETE"
    case .patch:
        return "PATCH"
    }
}

var containsBody: Bool {
    return self == .post || self == .put || self == .patch
}
}

final class MediaUploader: URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate {

    private let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    private let globalSSLEnabled: Bool = true
    var outputStream: OutputStream? = nil
    private var buffer:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    convenience init?(domain: String) {
        self.init(domain: domain)
    }

    func request(verb: HTTPVerb, action: String, parameters: JSONDictionary = [:], headers: [String : String] = [:], sslEnabled: Bool = true, media: MediaData, completion: @escaping (_ response: HTTPResponse) -> Void) {
        let sslEnabled = self.globalSSLEnabled || sslEnabled
        guard let request = buildRequest(verb: verb, action: action, parameters: parameters, media: media, sslEnabled: sslEnabled) else {
            return
        }

        headers.forEach { request.setValue($0.value, forHTTPHeaderField: $0.key) }

        let session = buildURLSession(sslEnabled: sslEnabled)

        conditionalLog(items: "REQUEST [\(verb.verbName)]")
        conditionalLog(items: "URL: \(request.url?.absoluteString ?? "[invalid]")")
        conditionalLog(items: "Headers: \(String(describing: request.allHTTPHeaderFields))")
        conditionalLog(items: "Parameters: \(parameters)")
        createSessionWithDataTask(session: session, request: request as URLRequest, mediaData: media, completion: completion)
    }

    func buildURLSession(sslEnabled: Bool) -> URLSession {
      if !sslEnabled {
          return URLSession(configuration: .default)
      }

      let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
      let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

      return session
    }

    func createSessionWithDataTask(session: URLSession, request: URLRequest, mediaData: MediaData,completion: @escaping (HTTPResponse) -> Void) {
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.lassie.dispatchgroup", attributes: .concurrent, target: nil)
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        queue.async(group: dispatchGroup) {
            self.dataTaskWorker(session: session, request: request as URLRequest, mediaData: mediaData, completion: completion)
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    func dataTaskWorker(session: URLSession, request: URLRequest, mediaData: MediaData, completion: @escaping (_ response: HTTPResponse) -> Void) {
        guard let data = mediaData.data() else {
            return
        }
        // let newTask = session.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request)
        // let newTask = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data)
        //session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data)

        let task = session.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request) { data, response, error in
            self.conditionalLog(items: "RESPONSE: \(String(describing: response))")

            if let eRROR = error {
                self.conditionalLog(items: "ERROR : \(String(describing: eRROR))")
            }
            self.parseResponse(data: data, response: response, error: error, completion: completion)
            session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
        }
        newTask.resume()
    }

    func buildRequest(verb: HTTPVerb, action: String, parameters: JSONDictionary = [:], media: MediaData, sslEnabled: Bool) -> NSMutableURLRequest? {
        let suffix = buildAction(verb: verb, action: action, parameters: parameters)
        guard let fullUrl = suffix.isEmpty ? baseURL(sslEnabled: sslEnabled) : URL(string: suffix, relativeTo: baseURL(sslEnabled: sslEnabled)), let mediaData = media.data() else {
            assert(false, "Invalid url/parameters")
            return nil
        }

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: fullUrl)
        request.httpMethod = verb.verbName
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        request.httpBody = mediaData
//        request.httpBodyStream = InputStream(data: mediaData)
        return request
    }

    // MARK: URLSessionDataTask

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, needNewBodyStream completionHandler: @escaping (InputStream?) -> Void) {
        self.closeStream()

        var inStream: InputStream? = nil
        var outStream: OutputStream? = nil
        Stream.getBoundStreams(withBufferSize: 4096, inputStream: &inStream, outputStream: &outStream)
        self.outputStream = outStream

        completionHandler(inStream)
    }

    private func closeStream() {
        if let stream = self.outputStream {
            stream.close()
            self.outputStream = nil
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        buffer.append(data)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) {
        let percentageSent = Double(totalBytesSent) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
        print("PERCENTAGE - \(percentageSent)")
    }

    private func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.allow)
    }

    private func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        if let e = error {
        print("ERROR")
        } else {
            self.conditionalLog(items: "RESPONSE DATA: \(String(data: buffer as Data, encoding: .utf8))")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but this is Swift. Use `URLRequest`, not `NS[Mutable]URLRequest`.

Comment: What is the "PATCH" http method? Don't you mean "POST"?

Comment: Why dontt you try https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload. If you still wanna go through manually I can check your code,

Comment: @Gihan, i don't want to put another dependency on the project, its just a upload method

Answer (score 0):

You are using `session.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request)`. The reason the file size is 0 on backend is you didn't close the stream, something like `inputStream.finished = true`. So you have to figure out when you want to close that stream.

Anyways, since you already have the data ready. i would say you can use `uploadTask(with:from:completionHandler:)`, or even switching to `uploadTask(with:fromFile:completionHandler:)`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the entire code, but I do close the stream, you can check on the class about that

Comment: why are you still using `httpBody` instead of `httpBodyStream`?